# Vaadin shows large error box in the UI and gets Detached Exception in the log

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security, vaadin

I am developing a vaadin application with spring security. I have set a defined time to Http session maximum inactive interval.

After the session is expired, the user should redirect to the login page.

But after the session is expired, UI promotes a large error box. If I click that error box or refresh the page, it successfully redirects to the login page. That's fine, but my concern is the large error message.

**SecurityConfig class**

```
public class SecurityConfig {

    private static final String LOGIN_PAGE = "/login";

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionFixation()
                        .migrateSession()
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                        .invalidSessionUrl(LOGIN_PAGE)
                        .maximumSessions(1)
                        .expiredUrl(LOGIN_PAGE))
                .formLogin(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

**CustomAuthenticationProvider class**

```
if(isAuthSuccess){
            Authentication authenticatedToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, new ArrayList<>());

            // Store the access and refresh token in the session
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedToken);
            ServletRequestAttributes request = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
            HttpSession session = request.getRequest().getSession(false);

            // Set session expiration based on access token expiration time
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(expiry_time);

            return authenticatedToken;

        }else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication failed");
        }
```

```
  @Override
    protected void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {
        UI ui = attachEvent.getUI();


        feederThread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    ui.access(() -> {
                        updateResults();
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    logger.error(e.getMessage() + " UI Error");
                }
            }
        });
        feederThread.start();
    }
```

UI Error erro log is returning when that large error box is showing.

**Error box**

[image]

**Log error**

[image]

I need to remove this erro box showing in the UI. Iam in beginer level in the vaadin development.

Comment: The UIDetachedException is natural. You have ever running background thread, eventually user will close the Browser / navigate to other page, but your thread is still running. Thus you need to catch that exception and stop the thread when UI has been detached.